# Hibernate @OneToOne cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am using JPA, Hibernate, Spring and MySQL

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db1`.`stock_detail`, CONSTRAINT `FK_STOCK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`STOCK_ID`) REFERENCES `stock` (`STOCK_ID`))

Create script

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock` (
  `STOCK_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `STOCK_CODE` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `STOCK_NAME` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=86 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock_detail` (
  `STOCK_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `COMP_NAME` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `COMP_DESC` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=72 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `stock`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`STOCK_ID`) USING BTREE,
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNI_STOCK_NAME` (`STOCK_NAME`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNI_STOCK_CODE` (`STOCK_CODE`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE `stock_detail`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`STOCK_ID`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE `stock`
  MODIFY `STOCK_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=86;

ALTER TABLE `stock_detail`
  MODIFY `STOCK_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=72;

ALTER TABLE `stock_detail`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_STOCK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`STOCK_ID`) REFERENCES `stock` (`STOCK_ID`);
```

Stock entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
@XmlRootElement
@Component("astock")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Stock.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Stock s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Stock.findByStockId", query = "SELECT s FROM Stock s WHERE s.stockId = :stockId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Stock.findByStockCode", query = "SELECT s FROM Stock s WHERE s.stockCode = :stockCode"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Stock.findByStockName", query = "SELECT s FROM Stock s WHERE s.stockName = :stockName")})
public class Stock implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID")
    private Integer stockId;
    @Basic(optional = false)

    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_CODE")
    private String stockCode;
    @Basic(optional = false)

    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_NAME")
    private String stockName;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "stock")
    private StockDetail stockDetail;
```

StockDetail entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock_detail")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "StockDetail.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM StockDetail s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "StockDetail.findByStockId", query = "SELECT s FROM StockDetail s WHERE s.stockId = :stockId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "StockDetail.findByCompName", query = "SELECT s FROM StockDetail s WHERE s.compName = :compName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "StockDetail.findByCompDesc", query = "SELECT s FROM StockDetail s WHERE s.compDesc = :compDesc")})
public class StockDetail implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID")
    private Integer stockId;
    @Basic(optional = false)

    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "COMP_NAME")
    private String compName;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "COMP_DESC")
    private String compDesc;
    @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID", referencedColumnName = "STOCK_ID")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Stock stock;
```

How I am trying to save it.

```
    Stock StockServices = (Stock) applicationContext.getBean("astock");

    Stock stock = new Stock();
    stock.setStockCode("123");
    stock.setStockName("AAPL");

    StockDetail stockDetail = new StockDetail();
    stockDetail.setCompName("Apple");
    stockDetail.setCompDesc("A hardware and software company");

    stockDetail.setStock(stock);
    stock.setStockDetail(stockDetail);

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(stock);
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to create primary keys on your tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to use `stock_detail.STOCK_ID` both as `PRIMARY KEY` for `stock_detail` and as `FOREIGN KEY` from stock and you assign different auto-increment values for them.

When Hibernate saves them it tries to save stock with `STOCK_ID =86` and `stock_detail` with `STOCK_ID=72` which breaks the foreign key contract.

Instead make a separate primary key in your `stock_detail` table  E.g `stock_detail_id` and leave `stock_id` as a separate column.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with accepted answer.

Still if you want to stick with Foreign key as primary key in child table, Go with `Foreign Key Generator` on child table. This way we can reduce the overhead to DB engine for creating too many unique ids.

Refer: [ForeignKeyGeneratorUsage](https://github.com/lovababu/HibernateForeignKeyGenerator)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't provide an optimal solution. The approach to use `stock.STOCK_ID` as the primary/foreign key of `stock_detail` should be kept for reasons outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13645562/10769628). And in JPA, this approach is supported as well, just use the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` and `@MapsId` annotations as outlined in section 4 of [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one)