# Where should put a foreign key when I want one to one relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am making user and address table. That would be one to one relationship. 
When I see some examples of company and user one to one relationship, company had a foreign key and user had no key assigned. 
How is it decideD?

Company table

```
  $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Comment: How about this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644979/mysql-one-to-one-relation

Answer (score 0):

I have take the example in laravel docs to explain your problem:

For example, a User model might be associated with one **Phone**. To define this relationship, we place a phone method on the  **User** model. The phone method should call the **hasOne** method and return its result:

```
Class User {
    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

then we can get phone that belong to user :

```
$phone = User::find(1)->phone;
```

Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, the **Phone** model is automatically assumed to have a **user_id** foreign key.

So, we can access the **Phone** model from our **User**. Now, let's define a relationship on the  **Phone** model that will let us access the User that owns the phone.

```
class Phone 
{
    /**
     * Get the user that owns the phone.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Here is a representation of tables :

```
___________                    __________
| User    |                    | Phone   |
|_________|                    |_________|
| id      |                    |   id    |
|_________|                    |_________|
| name    |                    | number  |
|_________|                    |_________|
| lastname|                    | user_id | ----------> foreign key 
|_________|                    |_________|
```